# JavaScript split array into dynamical number of arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a nice ES6 way of splitting an array into an array of arrays with each element in source array going into the next target array and repeating across all of the source array?

For example

```
source = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
```

if target arrays were 2 I would like to get output

```
output =  [ 
 [1,3,5,7,9,11,13],
 [2,4,6,8,10,12]
]
```

if target arrays were 3 I would like to get output

```
output =  [ 
 [1,4,7,10,13],
 [2,5,8,11],
 [3,6,9,12]
]
```

Comment: Can be done using `reduce`.

Comment: are you open to using the lodash method `_.chunk`?

Comment: JS can't have a structure like {[], [], ...}, it has to be [[], [], ...]. My answer posted below will create the correct structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `reduce`, it can be done. Here's the solution for a `size` of target array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13].reduce(function (acc, curr, idx) {
  acc[idx % size] ? acc[idx % size].push(curr) : acc[idx % size] = [curr];
  return acc
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was hoping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

1. Get the divisor and remainder
2. create a array of length n, with values `divisor + 1 ( for first remainder number of elements ) OR 0 ( we use this to equally distribute the extra elements to the initial elements )
3. Loop over the array we created above and slice the array and add to final array

```js
let source = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

let divideInParts = (arr, number) => {
  let divisor = Math.floor(arr.length / number)
  let remainder = arr.length % number
  let tempArr = Array.from({length: number}, (_,i)=> divisor +( remainder-- > 0 ))
  let start = 0
  let final = tempArr.map((v,i)=>{
    let val = i === 0 ? arr.slice(0, v) : arr.slice(start, start + v)
    start += v
    return val
  })
  return final
}

console.log(divideInParts(source, 2))
console.log(divideInParts(source, 3))
console.log(divideInParts(source, 13))
console.log(divideInParts(source, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this would work & along the lines of how I would write it but hoping to use ES6 syntax as it reduces the amount of code required for such array manipulation.